# Occurances generation in Recurring calendar items EWS

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

We want to perform synchronization of EWS recurring items. Can we store expanded individual occurrences? As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/recurrence-patterns-and-ews), recurring occurrences will be generated based on client requests. These generated occurrences are not permanently stored on the server. 
What does this mean exactly? How long occurrences will be stored? Will the itemid change in future for individual occurrence? Does it mean, we should not rely on individual occurrence item ids?
What is the best way to synchronize recurring appointments expecting updates in individual occurrences?

I have tried to fetch this info from Microsoft documentation but I couldn't get proper information.

Answer (score 0):

That means the occurrences do not physically exist - only the master appointment with the recurrence pattern blob does. Otherwise appointments with no end date would be problematic :-)

If you create a modified exception, it is stored as an attachment on the master occurrence.

The occurrences expanded when you, for example, request the user availability in a given time range.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Dmitry Streblechenko but document says generated occurances are not stored permanantly. Doest it mean expanded occurances will be deleted after smtime frame?

Comment: Once again, they do not physically exist. There is nothing to delete.

Comment: In this case, whenever client requests for expanding occurrences(which are not there in exceptions), how it will give the same item id for single occurrence ? What logic it will implement to give same item id every time?

Comment: They probably embed the date of the occurrence.